# C# Toggle bool upon key press

Tags: c#

I currently have a bool called debug. I want it so that when I press F10 it will set the bool to true, then if I press it again back to false and so on.

This is the code I am using:

```
bool debug = false;
        if (cVersion < oVersion)
        {
            Process.Start("http://consol.cf/update.php");
            return;
        }
        for (; ; )
        {
            if (debug)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please type in a command");
                cmd = Console.ReadLine();
                p.Send(cmd);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to execute config");
                Console.ReadLine();
                WebConfigReader conf =
                new WebConfigReader(url);
                string[] tokens = Regex.Split(conf.ReadString(), @"\r?\n|\r");
                foreach (string s in tokens)
                //ConsoleConfig cons = new ConsoleConfig();
                {
                    p.Send(s);
                    //p.Send(test);
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool debug = false;

public void Toggle()
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();

    if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.F10)
    {
        debug = !debug;
        if(debug)
        {
           //Your code here if debug = true
        }
        else
        {
           //Your code here if debug = false
        }
    }
    else
    {

        //Your code here if key press other than F10
    }
}
```

**ConsoleKeyInfo:** Describes the console key that was pressed, including the character represented by the console key and the state of the SHIFT, ALT, and CTRL modifier keys.

Try once may it help you.

Comment: @Lazarus Holl, please view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: @Lazarus Holl,  I update the answer view once may it help you :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the exact behaviour you want. You're probably best off rolling your own version of `Console.WriteLine`.

The following toggles `debug` and instantly switch to the other mode, ignoring any partially entered command.

```
private static bool InterruptableReadLine(out string result)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var info = Console.ReadKey(true);

    while (info.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter && info.Key != ConsoleKey.F10)
    {
        Console.Write(info.KeyChar);
        builder.Append(info.KeyChar);
        info = Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    result = builder.ToString();

    return info.Key == ConsoleKey.F10;
}

// reading input, or just waiting for enter in your infinite loop
string command;
var interrupted = InterruptableReadLine(out command);
if (interrupted)
{
    debug = !debug;
    continue;
}
// do stuff with command if necessary
```